# Mimick this progress bar example using jQuery / CSS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, progress-bar

I would like to develop a progress bar like the following: (taken from [ZocDoc.com](https://www.zocdoc.com/booking/start?startTime=634838256000000000&professionalId=41297&locationId=29436&specialtyId=345&procedureId=1296&referrerType=&repeatPatient=false))

[image: Example]

Can anyone point me in the right direction for where to start?

Comment: on the zocdoc.com, they just use three spans and they change background color on every step

Comment: Seems that you already found a design that you like. Did you look at the source for it? Is there something in particular that you don't understand that could for make a better question?

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery UI
http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: I think the OP wants a page progression indicator showing which steps are completed, rather than a progress bar

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to develop a progress bar or use a progressbar?

If you want to use one, like suggested just google it (jQuery UI or Bootstrap are my prefered ones)...

If you want to develop one, you should be more specific what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar in the link that you have provided is pure CSS (by pure CSS I mean that completed steps classes are still applied by javascript/jQuery) because it is actually not directly intractable with by the end user. However if you want the end user to be able to interact with it, then you would definitely need javascript/jQuery to develop such.